# bash script output to param

Tags: ros, roslaunch, script

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to take the output of a bash script and use it as a param in a ros launch file.
The script should also run in the same launch file

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243189/bash-script-output-to-param/) by [neobonde](https://answers.ros.org/users/27909/neobonde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think [roslaunch/XML/param](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/param)'s `command` attribute should do what you want:

> `command="$(find pkg-name)/exe '$(find pkg-name)/arg.txt'"` (*optional*)

> The output of the command will be read and stored as a string. It is strongly recommended that you use the package-relative `$(find)/file.txt` syntax to specify file arguments. You should also quote file arguments using single quotes due to XML escaping requirements.

I'm not sure what you mean with:

> The script should also run in the same launch file

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0